# How to implement Observer Pattern in PHP with global scope and persistance

Tags: php, html, publish-subscribe, observer-pattern, server-sent-events

The very basic idea of my goal is this:

1. User A submits a value via a form to `submit.php`
2. User B monitors the values submitted, which is updated via Server-Sent Event, pushed from `updates.php`.

`submit.php` handles writing the new value to the database, as well as notifying the observer object in `updates.php`.

Points of confusion:

1. Does each instance (session) of `updates.php` needs its own observer, as each user viewing the updates will be running their own instance of the script, or can they all share the same global observer object?
2. When the Subject Object loads, where is it going to get the observer objects? I can't store/put to sleep the observers, as they are active, right?
3. If I go with an ObjectStorage object, when the `submit.php` gets called and fetches it, are they observer objects actually *the* observer objects, by which I mean will calling their update method actually update the user's list?
4. How does I store/retrieve the ObjectStorage object from `submit.php` each time the form is submitted? Obviously I can't uses sessions, right? As those would be per-user?

Short version:  Is there a way to get a global, persistant object containing the Observers on the Subject side where the Observers are live objects?

If there are better or simpler approaches to this idea (or if I'm just totally confused and need educating) please let me know. But I am not looking for a framework that can already do it all, as I'm trying to use this project to better understand the Observer pattern as an idea.

Comment: You need persistent storage as PHP lacking support for such variables, you could store object to Memcached or Redis if available, or to serialize to file. I think you don't need observer here, from what i understand you want to implement. Maybe seperate table to track viewed submits?

Comment: Memcache is global? And the idea of using an observer is to avoid forcing the `updates.php` to poll for changes, as I see that as just passing the polling problem from the browser to the server, and thus diminishing the benefit of implementing server-sent events. Is an observer not the ideal server-side alternative to polling?

Comment: You can't setup a true observer pattern between browser and server. The best you could do is execute an AJAX call that has no timeout, and executes a server side PHP that also has no timeout, and monitors a database, file, or session variable for changes. As you might be aware, there are bigger issues with this. The polling pattern is the best you can get really.

Comment: Memcache is global, still you will need to notify client somehow that change accured (event fired), websockets?

Comment: @alickus : Server-sent events is another type of persistant connection in HTML5, similar to websockets, but server-to-client only, not bi-directional.

Comment: @crush - Server-Sent Events is the observer protocol for HTML5, where the browser (via js) establishes a listener URL and waits for the server to push data. Other than being easier to code, it's also better than polling because it's a persistant connection instead of a delayed ajax request.  It's going to be bigger than ice cream.  But, as I said before, I don't want to pass the job of polling on to the server (especially if it requires a db connection each time).

Comment: It's not widely supported, yet...

Comment: @crush : It's supported by the newest of all major browsers except (of course) IE. Part of the fun of this project is also figuring out an elegant way to use polling for backwards compatibility. And even if was only supported in one browser, I want to use this as a chance to test it out.

Comment: @Anthony, didn't realize this was an experimental application. I agree that SSEs are huge in the future, but IE is still a major portion of the market. In any practical application, IE cannot be ignored. Has jQuery provided a wrapper for SSE yet, that can resort to polling for IE?

Answer (score 1):

An important note for you to remember before the explanation:

> A design pattern is a solution created to solve a specific language-related problem (limitation). They are not design rules of thumb in software architecture at a language level.

I'm not sure on how you can see the Observer pattern, but I'll try to help you anyways:

1. No. Session in your case means user instance. You should, somehow, work with single abstract Observers that will handle all the instances of updates. The global Observer object is the way to go;
2. Yes, they are active objects, since the Observers register themselves with the Subject. At some point you are gonna have to intercept them;
3. Whenever the Subject changes, it broadcasts to all registered Observers that it has changed, and each Observer queries the Subject for that subset of the Subject’s state that it is responsible for monitoring. I guess you can figure that out from that;
4. That's really about implementation design. There is not a specific way to do it. You can try and see what suits you better;

Basically, yes, you can have a global Observer object, but that's not really the point of the pattern.

Try reading about the [implementation of the Observer pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) and see if that helps you at all.

Comment: I think the issue is that most of the examples (and probably the core idea of the pattern) is for real-time or inline changes to get broadcast, whereas this is a situation where the subject is the classic "stateless" object (meaning it starts at the top and finishes when it reaches the bottom), while the observer is in a persistant "live" state, needing to know when the subject changes, but the subject is getting destroyed and recreated at each change, so it's not a true "coupling" since the observer has to be re-attached each time. Is that why it seems off or am I still missing the point?

Comment: Remember that even if you have the destruction of the `Subject` on a regular basis, that doesn't mean he is stateless. But yes, it is kinda fuzzy to think about that specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you investigate [socket.io](http://socket.io).